# How do I change the 'name' HTML attribute of a Django Form field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django 3.0 form

```
# forms.py
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

This renders as the HTML element

```
<input type="text" name="email" required id="id_email">
```

Is there a way to change the 'name' attribute?

The [widgets documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances) suggests that either of these might work:

```
# forms.py
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {'name': 'email_address'}
        )
    )
```

or

```
# forms.py
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    email.widget.attrs.update({'name': 'email_address'})
```

but both render with *two* `name` attributes; the first one isn't replaced:

```
<input type="text" name="email" name="email_address" required id="id_email">
```

Is there a straightforward method of changing the `name` attribute?

I've found a couple of related previous posts, but the questions and answers tend to be old (Django 1.0-era) and more convoluted than this process ought to be.  I'm hoping that newer versions have a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the add_prefix method in your SignupForm to get the desired output

Update your form like this

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    custom_names = {'email': 'email_address'}

    def add_prefix(self, field_name):
        field_name = self.custom_names.get(field_name, field_name)
        return super(SignupForm, self).add_prefix(field_name)
        
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

to get a little insight of add_prefix method [check this out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/forms/)

Answer (score 2):

Change the variable name.

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
        email_address = forms.EmailField()
```

Comment: This is a good approach for fields that I've added to the form.  If I'm extending a form, however, like the `UserCreationForm` in this example, it will have its own fields already defined, like `username`.  I couldn't change the `name` attribute of those fields the way I could if something similar to the `widget.attrs{}` approach were possible, so it would still be good to know if something like that exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your form **manually** and write the **attribute names** yourself:

```
<form method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="email_address">
    <input type="text" name="username"> <!-- for example -->
    <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: While technically correct, this amounts to "don't use Django."  I'd prefer a solution that allows me to retain the benefits of a Django Form.

Comment: What exact benefit are you talking about?

Comment: The benefits of `UserCreationForm`'s built-in fields, built-in cleaning and error-checking, built-in error handling and reporting, ability to hook directly to the `Users` model, and the benefit of looping over form fields instead of typing in an entire form manually.

Comment: Alright then, if i'm not mistaken django grabs form field name values from their respective names on the models, I don't really see any reason to change the name of the form field to be different from the model field name unless you wanna make your code less readable, my best suggestion would be to just use `email` in both your form and your model